# Is there any other way so that i can get rid of this problem as my page.click() function is not working

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to **scrape** OLX cars data but I'm unable to click on load more .

Both code are not working

```js
await page.click('#container > main > div > section > div > div > div:nth-child(7) > div._3etsg > div > div.JbJAl > button')
await page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('#container > main > div > section > div > div > div:nth-child(7) > div._3etsg > div > div.JbJAl > button').click())
```

Comment: could you post more of your code? seeing your call in content would help out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is some error with your selector, this code is working for me on https://www.olx.in

```
await page.click("#container > main > div > section > div > div > div > div.JbJAl > button");
```

Can you check if this works?